# Is it possible to specify <SupportedCulture> from code behind

Tags: silverlight, localization, silverlight-4.0

Is there a way to specify the `<SupportedCulture>` from code behind? Or is there any way I can avoid specifying this tag in the project file?

**Edit:**
For HiTech Magic's comment.

I have sample browser contains, multiple samples. All will be dynamically displayed in the sample browser. What I'll create is Only XAML and it's code behind. My sample browser control will pick the files from the folder and display it in the sample browser. What I'm trying is, if I have the resx file and XAML and CS file my sample folder. The localization should work for me. For, this I'll not be able to edit the app it hosts these XAML's. To be specific I don't even have idea where the Sample hosting application will be.

Comment: If you don't have it the project will not know what resources to include. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Hi HiTech Magic, I have sample browser contains, multiple samples. All will be dynamically displayed in the sample browser. What I'll create is Only XAML and it's code behind. My sample browser control will pick the files from the folder and display it in the sample browser. What I'm trying is, if I have the resx file and XAML and CS file my sample folder. The localization should work for me. For, this I'll not be able to edit the app it hosts these XAML's. To be specific I don't even have idea where the Sample hosting application will be.

Comment: FYI, when responding to a specific comment use the @user: prefix in your response (in this case @HiTech:).  SO will then let the person know that you have responded.   Also when you have a lot of extra information to provide (the text of your comment is larger than the text of your question) then just edit your question instead.  If you want to let a specific commentator know about the edit just add a comment to the effect that you have edited your question.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones Thanks for the info. That was a cool feature.